# date calculation with full date in separate columns

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to make a query for the last 3 months of an item with my month and year in separate columns like so:

**YEAR_       PERIOD**

2014           5

2013           6

2013           11

2011           6

2009           2

The query needs to always start from the current month and year. I've tried using DateAdd(), DateSerial(), and DateDiff() none of those worked. Whenever I try to use **month(now()-3)**  i'm getting 2 instead of 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
DateDiff("m",CDate(Format([PERIOD] & "/" & [YEAR_],"mm/yyyy")),Now())
```

This took the two fields and made them a single date. I then took the difference from this month and the months between the two dates. I then set the criteria to <= 3.

**Addendum**

It can be simplified to:

```
DateDiff("m",CDate([PERIOD] & "/" & [YEAR_]),Date())
```

In general, however, you should never use string handling for dates if it can be avoided, and it easily can:

```
DateDiff("m",DateSerial([YEAR_],[PERIOD],1)),Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding or subtracting integers and dates simply adds or subtracts days from the date.  So `Now() - 3` results in 2016-02-15 (it is 2016-02-18 at the time of this posting).  That is clearly still the month of February - hence your result of two.

Give this a try `Month(DateAdd("m", -3, Now))`.  Here we are adding `-3` months to the current date and then getting the resulting month.  Based on today's date that will result in 11.